# Get strings which are inside double braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-grep

I have a string where some part of the string is inside braces, and I would like to get them in an array.

The string is for example: `Lorem {{ipsum}} dolor sit amet, {{consectetur}} adipiscing elit.`

And I would like to get: `array("ipsum", "consectetur")`

I tried this:

```
$regExp = "/\{\{([^)]+)\}\}/";
$result = preg_grep($regExp, array("Lorem {{ipsum}} dolor sit amet, {{consectetur}} adipiscing elit."));
```

but I get back the given string as result

Comment: use this regex `\{\{\K[^{}]*(?=}})` in `preg_match_all` function. http://regex101.com/r/hQ9dW1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong function, you should use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

You should also use lazy instead of greedy matching to avoid the result being `ipsum}} dolor sit amet, {{consectetur`. You can do that by adding a `?` after your quantifier:

```
$regExp = "/\{\{([^)]+?)\}\}/";
                      ^ here
preg_match_all($regExp, "Lorem {{ipsum}} dolor sit amet, {{consectetur}} adipiscing elit.",
               $result);

var_dump($result);
```

A [working example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tdO4Ao).

Comment: It's quite similar to my solution... Just a question: why do you need the [^)] part? Why do you want to exclude a closing parenthesis?

Comment: @TiborB. Actually, you don't need it. In this case `.+?` would do just as well as `[^)]+?`. However, I assume the OP uses it for a reason so I copied his expression to avoid breaking other stuff we don't see here.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_grep`

```
$str = 'Lorem {{ipsum}} dolor sit amet, {{consectetur}} adipiscing elit';
preg_match_all('!\{(\w+)\}!', $str, $m);
$result = array_map(function($v){return trim($v, '{}');},$m[0]);

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```